# Combobox inside ContextMenuStrip problem

Tags: winforms, events, combobox, contextmenu

Given the following insane setup (a ComboBox inside a UserControl inside a ToolStripControlHost inside a ContextMenuStrip):

[image]

there's something odd going on with clicking on different items in the ComboBox popup. If the item is inside the menu bounds (i.e. Amsterdam, Brussel or Luxemburg) the item is selected. If the item is outside the menu bounds (i.e. Berlijn and further) the menu is closed immediately.

Ignoring any spiffy remarks regarding the sheer crazy, anyone know what's going on and how to stop the menu from closing if a distant combobox item is selected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is due to a check deep in the ToolStripManager determining the mouse event is not on a child.

Basically you need to reject the ContextMenuStrip.OnClosing event if the ComboBox is displaying.  There's inevitably a cleaner solution but I didn't see one.

```
public bool IsDropDownShowing { get; private set; }
private void InitializeContextMenu()
{
    var userControl = new ComboMenuUserControl();
    var toolStripHost = new ToolStripControlHost(userControl);
    contextMenuStrip1.Items.Add(toolStripHost);

    userControl.comboBox1.DropDown += (o, args) => IsDropDownShowing = true;
    userControl.comboBox1.DropDownClosed += (o, args) => IsDropDownShowing = false;

    contextMenuStrip1.Closing += (o, args) =>
                                    {
                                        if (IsDropDownShowing == true)
                                            args.Cancel = true;
                                    };
}
```

Comment: Thanks John, looks very promising.